# Is it possible to change the value in readonly field

Tags: html, forms

In my website, I have a form which contains a readonly field in it . as follows.

```
<form method="post" action="database.php" id="myForm">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="url">This page URL:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="http://somthing.php" id="url" name="url" readonly>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="email" name="email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="errorline">Copy the error line:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="errorline" name="errorline"  required></textarea>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="correctedline">Corrected line:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="correctedline"  name="correctedline" required></textarea>
</div>
<button class="button button2" type="submit">&#128640; send</button>
</form>
```

the  value in the readonly field is changed to some irrelevant value say "http://hello.php" or "http://whatis.php" when I checked my database .
looking forward for comments.

Comment: Of course it's a **NO**. Read it here [<input> readonly Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Comment: then what is use of read only?

Comment: This thing is happening to me frequently, do you find some other reason?

Comment: This question is not about [tag:mysql], which you did tag, and it is about [tag:html], which you didn't tag. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to change the value in readonly field.

Yes it is

select that field in inspect element,change its readonly attribute,change the value and submit

So if you want to show something show it in label or something.don't put it in input field.If you really want to put it in input field put it and don't get values from it's post.Get that values by your self and insert it.

Comment: Thank you .. its working .. This is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

The readonly attribute applies to the display in the browser; the browser should prevent user from changing the displayed value in the input field.

Since the field is part of a form, when the form is posted, the value of the element is available in the $_POST data in database.php.

The script is free to retrieve the value, and do whatever it wants with it. It can ignore the value, or use the value in a SQL UPDATE statement. The "readonly" attribute doesn't affect what happens in database.php.